# Backbone View + Events

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

Why is the event not triggered if I click the button or trigger the event?
What do i miss?

```
<html>
<head><script src="jquery-1.7.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="underscore.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="backbone.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var SearchView = Backbone.View.extend({

    events: {
        "click #testid": 'savenow'
    },

    initialize: function(){
        console.log("init");
        console.log($('testid'));
    },

    savenow: function(){
        console.log("test save method");
    }
});

// The initialize function is always called when instantiating a Backbone View.
// Consider it the constructor of the class.
var search_view = new SearchView({ el: $('#testid') });
search_view.trigger("savenow", "test");
</script></head>
<body>
<h1>test</h1>
<input id="testid" type="button" value="testbutton" />
</body></html>
```

The example above is almost copied, but in my case it is not working.

Comment: `console.log($('testid'))` should be changed to `console.log($('#testid'))`, if you are trying to log the result of the jquery selector matching the element with id `testid`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your having a few issues. As the others answers suggest, the `events` object needs to be changed. This will bind the click event to `#testid` by default since that is the `el` of the view. Some reading on the subject [delegateEvents](http://backbonejs.org/#View-delegateEvents).

```
events: {
  'click' : 'savenow'
}
```

Your second problem is - the code is loading before the `DOM` is loaded. Which means, your view is unable to bind to the `testid` element. To fix this, you need to wrap your code in a [document.ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) function.

```
<script type="text/template">
  $(function() {
      /* All your code
       ...
       ...
       */
  });
```

A third issue is when you call `search_view.trigger("savenow", "test");` the `savenow` event is triggered, but nothing is listening for that event - so nothing appears to happen. You need to listen for that event on the view:

```
initialize: function(){
  console.log("init");
  this.on('savenow',this.savenow,this); 
   // or this.listenTo(this,'savenow',this.savenow);
}
```

A working code example:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="jquery-1.7.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="underscore.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="backbone.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      // Run this block of code when the DOM is loaded.
      $(function() {

        var SearchView = Backbone.View.extend({

          // Listen for click events on this view's element - '#testid'.
          events: {
            "click": 'savenow'
          },

          initialize: function(){
            console.log("init");
            // listen for the savenow event triggered by this view.
            this.listenTo(this,'savenow',this.savenow);
          },
          savenow: function(){
            console.log("test save method");
          }
        });

        var search_view = new SearchView({ el: '#testid' });
        search_view.trigger("savenow", "test");
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>test</h1>
    <input id="testid" type="button" value="testbutton" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: perfect answer. Thanks! It helped me a lot with the understanding. Maybe one more question. The this.listenTo runs into a "Object [object Object] has no method..."

Comment: Glad I could help. My first guess would be the context your calling it? What are you doing differently than [here](http://jsbin.com/ERImog/1/edit).

Comment: it looks like the only difference are the "script imports". Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You're giving the el as #testid - Then, you're telling it to look inside #testid for #testid when you configure events: as

```
events:{
"click #testid":"savenow"
}
```

By changing the events object to

```
events:{
"click":"savenow"
}
```

You are just targeting all of the view's el (in this case, #testid).

Alternatively, you can keep your events configuration as you had it, and change the el to be body, or parent div of your search panel (which I assume contains the text input field or other settings, as well as the button).

Comment: hmm i just tried it with "click":"savenow" but this has no effect

Comment: In that case I would remove the { el: '#testid' } from creating the SearchView. Views in Backbone should generate their own el's inside the render function. This is likely the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
events: {
    "click": 'savenow'
},
```

Here you go! Event type without a selector adds the event listener on the view `el` itself.